# range parameter for any iterable input with properly convertible elements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, rvalue, std-ranges

I am currently trying to get used to C++20 especially concepts and ranges in this case. Hopefully the title fits my problem I am not really sure yet what I ran into.

I want to create a set method for my `class AttribueMap` to pass any iterable input with the underlying type that is convertible to `string` to my class. The class is holding a simple `map< string, vector< string >>`.
The concept I am using is the following:

```
template< typename input_data_t, typename range_element_t >
concept is_range_with_elements_of_type = std::ranges::input_range< input_data_t > 
&& std::convertible_to< std::ranges::range_value_t< input_data_t >, range_element_t >;
```

When I pass `vector< string >` or `array< string >` or even `vector< const char* >` it works. But `initializer_list< const char* >` or a `static constexpr array< string_view >` doesn't work.

I get the feeling its about the rvalue types, so how can I set the constraints for the set method to work with this type of temporary input, too?

---

The boiled down code:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>

template< typename input_data_t, typename range_element_t >
concept is_range_with_elements_of_type = std::ranges::input_range< input_data_t > && std::convertible_to< std::ranges::range_value_t< input_data_t >, range_element_t >;

class AttributeMap
{
public:
    using attribute_name_t = std::string;
    using attribute_element_t = std::string;
    using attribute_data_t = std::vector< attribute_element_t >;

    template< typename input_data_t >
    requires is_range_with_elements_of_type< input_data_t, attribute_element_t >
    bool setAttribute(const attribute_name_t&, const input_data_t&)
    {
        if constexpr (std::convertible_to< input_data_t, attribute_element_t>)
        {
            //currently not implemented
            return false;
        }
        else if constexpr (is_range_with_elements_of_type< input_data_t, attribute_element_t >)
        {
            //currently not implemented
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    std::map< attribute_name_t, attribute_data_t > m_data;
};


#include <array>

int main()
{
    AttributeMap dut;

    dut.setAttribute("Friends", { "Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen" }); //error
    dut.setAttribute(std::string("other Friends"), std::array<std::string, 4>{ "Milo of Croton", "Cleopatra", "300", "..." });
    dut.setAttribute(std::string("even more Friends"), std::vector<const char*>{ "Karl", "Gilgamesh" });
    {
        const std::string attribute{ "books" };
        const std::vector< std::string > attributeData{ "Book1", "Book2" };
        dut.setAttribute(attribute, attributeData);
    }
    {
        const std::string attribute{ "Cloths" };
        const std::array< std::string, 5 > attributeData{ "Shirt", "Pullover", "Jeans", "Cap", "Sneaker" };
        dut.setAttribute(attribute, attributeData);
    }
    {
        const std::string attribute{ "Comments" };
        static constexpr std::array< std::string_view, 3 > attributeData{ "great", "rofl u said lol", " . " };
        dut.setAttribute(attribute, attributeData); //error
    }
}
```

The errors I get with msvc (14.36.32502) are:

> Error C2672   'AttributeMap::setAttribute': no matching overloaded function found

for the lines 11:

> `dut.setAttribute("Friends", { "Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen" });`

and the last

> `dut.setAttribute(attribute, attributeData);`

in line 27, using `static constexpr std::array< std::string_view, 3 >`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But `initializer_list< const char* >` or a `static`
> `constexpr array< string_view >` doesn't work.

`{}` does not participate in template deduction, so the compiler does not know the type of `{ "Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen" }`. You can explicitly specify the type or add a default template parameter for `setAttribute`

```
template<typename input_data_t = std::initializer_list<attribute_element_t>>
  requires is_range_with_elements_of_type< input_data_t, attribute_element_t>
bool setAttribute(const attribute_name_t&, const input_data_t&);
```

For `array<string_view, N>`, the problem is that `string_view` cannot be implicitly converted to `string`, which means the following assertion fails

```
static_assert(std::convertible_to<std::string_view, std::string>); // failed
```

which makes the constraint not satisfied. One of the workarounds is to use `constructible_from` instead of `convertible_to` to compose `is_range_with_elements_of_type` concept

```
template<typename input_data_t, typename range_element_t>
concept is_range_with_elements_of_type = 
  std::ranges::input_range<input_data_t> && 
  std::constructible_from<range_element_t, std::ranges::range_value_t<input_data_t>>;
```

in which case you need to explicitly call the constructor to construct the `string`.

Answer (score 2):

In

```cpp
dut.setAttribute("Friends", { "Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen" });
```

you have a [*braced-init-list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

```cpp
{ "Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen" }
```

which can be used to list-initialize an object, but you've left it up to template argument deduction to figure out what type of object `input_data_t` is that should be initialized.

The compiler has a *braced-init-list* ready to initialize an object but no information about what type to initialize, so compilation fails.

You can either specify the type of object at the call site, like a `std::initializer_list<const char*>`:

```cpp
dut.setAttribute("Friends", 
                 std::initializer_list<const char*>{"Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen"});
```

or add an overload that takes a `std::initializer_list` with elements convertible to `attribute_element_t`:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename input_data_t>
requires is_range_with_elements_of_type<std::initializer_list<input_data_t>,
                                        attribute_element_t>
bool setAttribute(const attribute_name_t& an,
                  std::initializer_list<input_data_t> il)
{
    //...
}
```

---

From [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):
A `std::initializer_list` object is automatically constructed when:

- a *braced-init-list* is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
- a *braced-init-list* is used as the right operand of assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
- a *braced-init-list* is bound to `auto`, including in a ranged `for` loop
  Which means that this will magically work:

  ```
  auto il = {"Chery", "Jack", "Nguyen"};
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(il),
                std::initializer_list<const char*>>);
  dut.setAttribute("Friends", il);
  ```

  ... but skipping binding to `auto` like in your code will not.